# Caching user permissions in redis, good idea?

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis

For last few days I am working on improving app performance. What do you think about caching user data and permission in redis? In my case every time when user create post or try to upload file app check in database, if user exist and fetch user permission and role. My first idea was to put permission and user role in session but user can have multiple session on different device, so every time when user get ban or user permission change app need to update every user's session and as far as I know express-session do not support this kind of feature.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's a very open question with no strict answer. But as an advice, I'd say Redis is **perfect for storing user session** altogether. Moving parts of the session would still require you to query the database (you get the session, you must query for user information, and also ping Redis for permissions & roles). So I think you should put all session data in one place, and the fastest would be Redis. It would also let you save that data so it's not entirely in the memory. There are also many ways to optimize it, like when to write the data (like every second) and so forth.

Querying Redis is extremely fast and efficient since you don't have any user to user relations, and most of the times you won't search on anything different than "get me that user session by id".

It's a very standard solution to put user session in Redis, if not the most often used one :) Good luck!